# Entering file locations in the Deployment Manager screen in Delphi XE7 for iOS

Tags: ios, delphi-xe7

This question is related to my last question regarding file locations on the iOS platform. The TPath functions work a treat - thanks for the answer ([Operation not permitted when trying to create a TFileStream Object on iOS8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26467536/operation-not-permitted-when-trying-to-create-a-tfilestream-object-on-ios8)). I now have a problem with the database, initially I bundled it with the App which worked fine for reading data, but I can not write to the database because it is in the app folder. I have read the Apple developer documentation regarding db files and it suggests putting db files in to the apps Library folder. My question is how to enter this location into the deployment manager in XE7 I have tried .\Library\DBFolder but that does not work. I read the help file in XE7 which suggested putting user files in StartUp\Documents and retrieve the path programmatically using 'TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'filename')' again, this does not work. 
Thanks in advance.
Charlie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok until I hear otherwise, this looks like it can't be done. The solution is Transfer the files in question to the read only bundle folder then on first launch, copy the files to the application's Library folder - it just slows down the first launch a little - but it works a treat.